How to read and decode the temperature from a thermostat using Python
im new to programming with Python so please excuse me if I´m missing some fundamentals.
For my project I need to log the temperature of an thermostat (JUMO eTron 100) which is connectet to my PC via USB. The temperature is messured with an PT100 temperature sensor which is connected to the analog input of the thermostat.
I managed to get a working code that gets data from the device. But the value (4939.3 °C) is obviusly false. As I can also see on the display that the temp. is 21.4 °C.
See my code below:
import usb.core
import usb.util
import time
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import os


# Search for Jumo-Thermostat via USB-ID 
DEVICE_VENDOR_ID = 0x1B3A  # VID 
DEVICE_PRODUCT_ID = 0x01AB # PID 

# Connect to the device
device = usb.core.find(idVendor=DEVICE_VENDOR_ID, idProduct=DEVICE_PRODUCT_ID)

if device is None:
    raise ValueError("Device not found.")

# configuration with the device
device.set_configuration()

# Excel-Datei initialisieren
excel_file = "temperaturdaten_jumo_usb.xlsx"
def initialize_excel():
    if not os.path.exists(excel_file):
        workbook = Workbook()
        sheet = workbook.active
        sheet.title = "Temperaturdaten"
        sheet.append(["Zeitstempel", "Temperatur (°C)"])
        workbook.save(excel_file)
        print("Neue Excel-Datei mit Kopfzeilen erstellt.")

initialize_excel()

# Function to query the temperature 
def lese_temperatur():
    try:
        device.write(0x02, b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x84\x0A')
        response = device.read(0x81, 64)  # read answer
        
     
        print("Rohdaten (Hex):", ' '.join(f'{byte:02x}' for byte in response)) #show raw data in Hexform
        
        for i in range(len(response) - 1):
            temp_raw = int.from_bytes(response[i:i+2], byteorder='big')  
            temperature = temp_raw / 10.0  
            print(f"Bytes {i}-{i+1}: Wert = {temperature} °C")
               
        
        temperature = int.from_bytes(response[3:5], byteorder='big') / 10.0
        return temperature
    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        print(f"USB-Fehler: {e}")
        return None

# Main loop for Data evaliuation
try:
    while True:
        temperature = lese_temperatur()
        if temperature is not None:
            timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            print(f"{timestamp} - Temperatur: {temperature} °C")
            
            # Save temperature in Excel 
            workbook = load_workbook(excel_file)
            sheet = workbook.active
            sheet.append([timestamp, temperature])
            workbook.save(excel_file)
        
        time.sleep(5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Datenerfassung gestoppt.")

My asumtion was that the data format or protocol is not interpreted correctly. So I changed the code to show the raw data in Hex-Form and also show all possible Byte variations. The result looks like this:
Rohdaten (Hex): 01 83 02 c0 f1
Bytes 0-1: Wert = 3353.7 °C
Bytes 1-2: Wert = 64.3 °C
Bytes 2-3: Wert = 4915.4 °C
Bytes 3-4: Wert = 6188.8 °C
2024-11-12 11:37:14 - Temperatur: 4939.3 °C

Which makes still no sense to me. Also even if I change the temp. by applying heat to the sensor non of the values change.
So im guessing there is still a problem with the data evaluation. But Im out if ideas at this point.

The comment is too complex for us to work with it. Maybe someone with the same kind of develop in a similar thermostat can help you. Anyways, my advice is try to isolate where you capture the wrong value and check why it is wrong. Maybe it's not the temperature what you are reading or maybe you need to decript it somehow.

You should check the device documentation to understand the format of the data that it presents.
